Made a mistake in Salat with a mispronunciation accident
During sujood in the second rakat, I said Subhaana robbiyal-a'alaa, Subhaana robbiyal-a'alaa, and then in the third time of saying it I said Subhaana robbiyal-a'alaam by accident. Does that invalidate my prayer? I also did sujood sahw for that mistake.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the StackExchange model consider taking the tour] and checking our [help].

The prayer must be performed correctly, and one cannot add or remove anything to the prayer that does not belong to it, or that which belongs to the prayer. If someone adds something to the prayer out of forgetfulness, their prayer remains valid, but they must perform سُجود السهو (Sujood as-Sahw) to compensate for the mistake. However, if the addition is done intentionally, the prayer becomes invalid, and it is obligatory for the person to repeat the prayer.
For example, if someone omits the bowing by forgetfully doing it, he must make it up by Sujud Sahw. If one realizes he is adding a extra rakat then it is obligatory upon him to return to the tashahud and complete taslim.
For your case, what you did was completely permissible, since you did it more then once, three times is only a sunnah. It is permissible to complete sujud sahw before taslim, if the sunnah act is omitted, however a obligatory act being omitted will make sujud sahw obligatory on the person.
The evidence for this is

“If any one of you prays and doubts, and he does not know how much he
has prayed, he should perform two prostrations before completing the
prayer, and this is the sujood of forgetfulness.” (Sahih Muslim 572b)


Your exampe for sujood as-sahw is wrong, because there's no amount of times one should say subhana rabiyya al-'Adheem which was prescribed, since saying so is sunnah. so there's no reason here to perform sujud as-Sahw no matter if it was intentional of out of forgetfulness.

@Medi1Saif Jazakallahu Khair! Definetely, I know this, but this answer accidentaly slipped out!
